# Autolayout - How to align with longest item

Tags: ios, autolayout

Suppose I have a view that contains two columns of objects. The first column contains labels, and the second column contains, say, sliders. I want the sliders all to align left with each other. I want the labels all to align left with each other. The trick is, how can I set the spacing between the labels and sliders so that the default spacing is used between the left sliders and the longest label, thus:

```
label 1            slider 1
label 2            slider 2
longer label 3     slider 3
very long label 4[]slider 4
label 5            slider 5
```

I've placed square brackets, [], where the default spacing should be. Is it possible to add this sort of constraint in the storyboard (iOS 7)? If so, how? The trick is that I don't know which label is the longest, especially with localization.

Ideally, I could specify a bounding box around the labels and align the sliders with the right side of the bounding box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in IB. All the labels should have their left edges aligned, and one of them should have a fixed space to the left edge of their superview (all the elements should be enclosed in a UIView). Similarly, the sliders would have their right edges aligned and one of them would have a fixed space to the right edge of the box. Give one of the labels a horizontal spacing constraint to a slider -- make that a short one, say ==8 with a priority of 900 (that's the important thing). Now, give all the labels a >= constraint with whatever value you want for the minimum spacing (and leave the priority at 1000).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. All elements should be enclosed in a UIView. You mean, other than the view controller's main view? To what end? I normally do this to make rotation issues easier to resolve. But I don't see how it's related to this issue. Also, what is the "box"?

Comment: OK. I think I follow what you're after, but I don't think the sliders need to be aligned to anything other than each other horizontally. Basically, you set one of the label/slider spacings to a small space with low priority and all the others to the desired spacing with higher priority. That forces them to shift right. I'll try that and see if it works. I guess I've never used inequalities in constraints before.

Comment: I accepted your answer but edited it to match what I actually did. I also tried clarifying a bit.

Comment: @VictorEngel, I was putting them in a "box" because I thought that's what you meant by a bounding box, but yeah, there's no need to have that, as long as they're all aligned with each other.

Comment: OK. But I still don't know what a "box" is. Were you suggesting a UIView that the other objects would all fit in? I guess it doesn't matter now, since I gleaned what works from your answer. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @VictorEngel, yes, by the box, I meant the UIView that everything was contained in.